# how to do you end a call at work for a tornado warning

Tags: word-usage, usage

What is the best way to end a call at a business for a tornado warning when you are advised to go to the shelter?

Comment: How about "There is a tornado warning. I have to go to a shelter. I will speak to you later." (Or "please call me back later".)

Comment: This is more about business etiquette than about the English language

Answer (score 2):

There are no magic words for this situation. Just tell the other person what is happening.

> There is a tornado warning, and I have to go to the shelter.

You see there are no special words.  Just normal English. There are several thousand other ways to say this.

Comment: I would suggest some politeness at having to end the call abruptly. Firm politeness, of course, because survival is infinitely more important than a phone call, but it _is_ an abrupt end to the phone call.

Comment: Of course.  But there are 101 ways to add politeness or firmness.  But still no magic words.

Comment: It's a tornado warning.  Don't dawdle.  *"Hey, sorry, i have to go.  There's a tornado warning.  I'll call you back when it's clear.  Bye."*   Either that or, if you have service in the shelter and it's not too rude to the other people in there with you, *"I'll call you from the shelter."*